# How do I set a JButton to erase a JTextArea, then re-add everything, plus something else?

Tags: java, text, netbeans, replace, settext

```
private void initializeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

List <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");


List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
Collections.sort(sorted);

    bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");

    for (String o : cdList)  {
    bigBox.append(o);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }

    bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");

    for (String s : sorted)  {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }

}                                                

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

String newCD = cdInput.getText();

List <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");
cdList.add(""+newCD);

List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
Collections.sort(sorted);

    bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");

    for (String o : cdList)  {
    bigBox.append(o);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }

    bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");

    for (String s : sorted)  {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }
```

I need the second button to simply add whatever's in the cdInput box.

I'm supposed to add more text, so I'll add it here
Yolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololoolololololololoololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?  Which methods will be called in what sequence and what should each of those methods do? To get content: getText() / to clear: setText("") / to set the text: setText(THETEXTTOSET);

Comment: I'll press the initializeButton first, it'll output the text, then I wanna press the addButton, and have it simply add text from the cdInput

Comment: Do a getText() from the source and an append() to the target.